# NestJS - Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local"

Tags: javascript, authentication, passport.js, nestjs, passport-local

These are the partial NestJS code snippets I have. I am trying to implement the passport local strategy for getting the username and password. I am getting -Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local", in the controller file when using the auth guard.

AuthModule.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { JwtAuthController } from './jwt-auth.controller';
import { JwtAuthService } from './jwt-auth.service';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.SECRETKEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '3600s' }
    })
  ],
  controllers: [JwtAuthController],
  providers: [JwtAuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [JwtAuthService],
})
export class JwtAuthModule {}
```

local.strategy.ts

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtAuthService } from './jwt-auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'local') {
  constructor(private authService: JwtAuthService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser({username, password});
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

app.controller.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Post, Req, UnauthorizedException, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtAuthService } from './jwt-auth/jwt-auth.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {

  constructor(private readonly authService: JwtAuthService)  {}
  
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('/auth/login')
  async login(@Req() req) {
    return this.authService.login(req.user)
  }
  
}
```

I am getting the following error on calling /auth/login API

```
[Nest] 26753  - 10/31/2021, 22:08:18   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unknown authentication strategy "local"
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local"
```

Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which module `AppController` lives?

Comment: AppController is in app.module.ts. I have exported auth.service.ts from the auth.module and auth.module is imported in app.module.ts

Comment: Is your `JwtAuthService` `REQUEST` scoped?

Comment: I am new to NESTjs. How can I find out if the JwtAuthService REQUEST scoped?

Comment: Try to add the `AuthModule` to your imports of `app.module.ts`.

Comment: @adhinarayan  I also get this same error. Did you get the answer?

Comment: I stilll could not get a working solution.

Answer (score 5):

Such an old question with no answers...

In my case I was having sort of an cyclic dependency issue. Or at least it was what it looked like. Cyclic deps can be either on nest side or even on node.js require side (on the second case we end up with empty imports).

Case 1:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyLocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(PassportLocalStrategy) {
  hello = 'hello'

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    console.log('load local strategy')
  }
}


@Module({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      async useFactory(config: ConfigService) {
        const jwtSecret = config.get('APP_KEY')
        const expiresIn = config.get('AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRED')
        return {
          secret: jwtSecret,
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn,
          },
        }
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    RoleService,
    JwtStrategy,
    JwtService,
    AuthService,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {
  constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    const moduleRef = this.moduleRef
    console.log('init auth module')
    const local = moduleRef.get(MyLocalStrategy)
    const auth = moduleRef.get(AuthService)
    console.log('my modules', { local, auth }, local?.hello)
  }
}
```

In this case the "load local strategy" never got logged. Yet "my modules" logged an empty localStrategy instance, without my "hello" property. Weird!

I hacked a fix by moving the class instantiation to a factory provider, and by requiring the dependencies with `ModuleRef`. The following excerpt worked fine.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      async useFactory(config: ConfigService) {
        const jwtSecret = config.get('APP_KEY')
        const expiresIn = config.get('AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRED')
        return {
          secret: jwtSecret,
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn,
          },
        }
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    RoleService,
    JwtStrategy,
    JwtService,
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: MyLocalStrategy,
      useFactory: (moduleRef: ModuleRef) => {
        const auth = moduleRef.get(AuthService)
        console.log('local strat factory', { auth })
        return new MyLocalStrategy(auth)
      },
      inject: [ModuleRef],
    },
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {
  constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    const moduleRef = this.moduleRef
    console.log('init auth module')
    const local = moduleRef.get(MyLocalStrategy)
    const auth = moduleRef.get(AuthService)
    console.log('local', { local, auth }, local?.hello)
  }
}
```

I also tried factory + injecting AuthService directly (through providers array, instead of using `ModuleRef`). I got a null AuthService.

Probably some dependency cycle on the node.js module imports, tough neither eslint or nest wouldn't say anything.

Comment: Had the same issue here with cyclic dependency. I was injecting the `@Inject(REQUEST)` in a service.

Comment: @ConradoFonseca same here. can't believe its an old issue and never got fixed. Flagged it to them https://github.com/nestjs/passport/issues/1561

Answer (score 4):

just add the PassportModule and LocalStrategy in app.module .it will be fixed

```
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule],
  providers: [AuthService,LocalStrategy],
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you explain why it works?

Answer (score 1):

Fix Bug https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4646

File AUTH.ts

```
enter code here

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { JwtAuthController } from './jwt-auth.controller';
import { JwtAuthService } from './jwt-auth.service';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Module({
imports: [
UserModule,
PassportModule.register({defaultStrategy:'local'}),
JwtModule.register({
  secret: process.env.SECRETKEY,
  signOptions: { expiresIn: '3600s' }
})
],
controllers: [JwtAuthController],
providers: [JwtAuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
exports: [JwtAuthService],
})
export class JwtAuthModule {}
```

Comment: I tried adding defaultStrategy, but it still is not working. I am getting the same error.

Comment: @adhinarayan did you get a solution? I am also facing the same problem not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: how did you resolve this @adhinarayan?

Answer (score 1):

NestJs encourages scalability and therefore organizes your code in modules.
Instead of calling `JwtAuthService` method in the `AppController`, do it in the `JwtAuthController`. Your code should look like this:

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Post, Req, UnauthorizedException, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtAuthService } from './jwt-auth.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class JwtAuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: JwtAuthService)  {}
  
  @Post('/login')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  async login(@Req() req) {
    return req.user
  }
  
}
```

Nest will then instantiate all providers in the `JwtAuthModule` such that it will be available in it's controller (`JwtController`).

You Can always optimize your code by moving `AuthGuard` to it own file `local.guard.ts` given you the possibility to do any additional business logic.

```
import { ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Request } from 'express';

export class LocalGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your auth module is being imported in your entry file. app.module.ts.

My auth-module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UsersModule } from 'src/users/users.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Module({
 imports:[UsersModule,PassportModule],
 providers: [AuthService,LocalStrategy]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

My app module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UsersModule } from 'src/users/users.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Module({
  imports:[UsersModule,PassportModule],
 providers: [AuthService,LocalStrategy]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module that implements the authentications.

It can be inside `app.module.ts` or inside another module that is connected to it.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';

@Module({
    imports: [UsersModule, AuthModule],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that may clarify things better

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#request-scoped-strategies

Answer (score 0):

Recently I ended up facing this error due to my organization of the folder it seems not finding the files `local.strategy` and `jwt.strategy`, in each Guard I had to add a constructor importing the Strategy.

Try to see if creating this Guard solves your problem

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

And replace the `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))` with `@UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)`

If you still have an error, change your file by adding the construction like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  constructor(private readonly localStrategy: LocalStrategy) {
    super();
  }
}
```

If this does not work, the real reason for this error is related to scope request injection, apparently a middleware must be ignoring the execution of the LocalAuthGuard middlware. For example: a multi-tenant connection, if you get the name of the database from the request, may end up ignoring the execution of LocalAuthGuard, because in the file `local.strategy.ts` you are using the constructor `private authService: AuthService` and if it really is making multi tenant connection review how you are injecting the repository in your file called `UsersService`.

Hope this helps anyone looking with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `AuthModule` to your imports of `app.module.ts`
Ensure it appears before any other of you own module

Answer (score 0):

**The following helped me:**

Try to import "Strategy" from **'passport-local'** instead of **'@nestjs/passport'**

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy)
```

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue with you. My solution is importing `LocalStrategy` class to module file, in which I use `AuthGuard` for API endpoint.

For example: in file `user.controller.ts` I have `AuthGuard('local')` in the endpoint `/login` with method `POST`

```
//user.controller.ts

@UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
@Post('login')
async login (@Request() req: any) {
  return req.user;
}
```

In my case, I just add `LocalStrategy` class (I also have this class in `local.strategy.ts` like you) in module file:

```
//user.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    LocalStrategy,
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  ...
}
```

Conclusion, [`NestJs`](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication) is quite complicated in importing modules, don't forget to import what you want into other modules. Good luck!